# Fastest way to determine if two strings differ by a single letter in a large set of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare two strings and add one of the strings to a list if they are almost equal (differ by a single letter). What would be the fastest way to do this as my set of words is over 90k and doing this often takes too long?

EDIT: one of the words (comparison_word in code below) does not change.

EDIT2: the words must be of equal length

This is my current code:

```
    for word in set_of_words:
        amount = 0  
        if len(word) == len(comparison_word):
            for i in range(len(word)):
                if comparison_word[i] != word[i]:
                    amount += 1
            if amount == 1:
                list_of_words.append(word)
    return list_of_words
```

Comment: What about `foo` and `fo`?

Comment: How does your 'set of words' change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following searches my dictionary of 61K words in about 25 msec.

```
import re

def search(word, text):
    ws = [r'\b{}[^{}]{}\b'.format(w[:i],w[i],w[i+1:]) for i in range(len(word))]

    for mo in re.finditer('|'.join(ws), text):
        yield mo.group()

with open("/12dicts/5desk.txt") as f:
    text = f.read()

for hit in search('zealoos', text):
    print(hit)                         #prints zealous
```

Presuming that the list of strings is in a file, one string per line, read it in as one long string and use a regular expression to search the string for matches.

`search()` takes a word like 'what' and turns it into a regular expression like this:

```
\b[^w]hat\b|\bw[^h]at\b|\bwh[^a]t\b|\bwha[^t]\b
```

And then scans all the words and find all the near misses--at C-speed.

Answer (score 2):

You might find zip is a more efficient than indexing:

```
def almost_equal(set_of_words,comp):
    ln = len(comp)
    for word in set_of_words:
        count = 0
        if len(word) == ln:
            for a, b in zip(word, comp):
                count += a != b
                if count == 2:
                    break
            else:
                yield word
```

Demo:

```
In [5]: list(almost_equal(["foo","bar","foob","foe"],"foa"))
Out[5]: ['foo', 'foe']
```

Comment: This, along with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36208085/3566755) brought my average time down to 28 seconds from 40 seconds

Comment: appending to a list may be very slightly faster

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to reduce the amount of work being done:

```
n_comparison_word = len(comparison_word)
for word in set_of_words:
    amount = 0
    n_word = len(word)
    if n_word != n_comparison_word:
        continue
    for i in range(n_word):
        if comparison_word[i] != word[i]:
            amount += 1
        if amount == 2:
            break
    if amount == 1:
        list_of_words.append(word)
return list_of_words
```

Some notes:

- The value of `len(comparison_word)` needs to be computed only once (ever).
- The value of `len(word)` needs to computed once (per iteration of the loop).
- You know you can stop looking at a word when `amount` reaches the value 2 (or more - in any case that word can no longer be part of the result).

It may be worth reading [this part of the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) regarding the `continue` and `break` statements which are both used in the code.

Comment: I think they are trying to compare all the words with each other. So I imagine the first step would be to create a dictionary of words lengths where each hash held a list of unique words.

Comment: This brought my average time down to 30 seconds from 40 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done exhaustive testing, but if `comparison_word` is not too long (fewer than 6 letters), and your `set_of_words` can change, then it might be worth it to compute all acceptable words, store those in a set, a simply iterate through `set_of_words` and test for `word in acceptable_words`.

If not, here's my take on your code:

```
for word in set_of_words:
  different_letter_exists = False
  length = len(word)
  if length == len(comparison_word):
    for i, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter != comparison_word[i]:
            if different_letter_exists:
                break
            else:
                different_letter_exists = True
    if i == length:
        list_of_words.append(word)
```

Essentially: for every word, once you encounter an different letter, `different_letter_exists` is set to True. If you encounter it again, you break out of the loop. A new word is only added if `i == length`, which only happens if `enumerate` gets all the way to the end, which only happens if only one different letter exists.

Good luck :)